# Forcing two xAxis to be the same in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

At the moment I have two entirely different charts

```
$(div).highcharts({
        title: {
            text: ""
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: "datetime",
        },
        legend: {
          enabled: false  
        },
        yAxis: yAxis.ranking,
        series: data.rankings
    });
```

and

```
$(div + "Count").highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
        },
        title: {
            text: ""
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: "datetime",
        },
        yAxis: yAxis.count,
        series: data.counts
    });
```

I need the xAxis of both to match up identically. Both charts ordinarily have 4 series and tend to line up quite nicely, however in the scenario where they have between 1 and 3 series, then the second chart goes out of sync with the top one and centres in the middle with a big amount of whitespace on either side.

I was wondering if there was a way to force the second graph to take on the exact xAxis of another graph.

Comment: can you add your full chart code? like with data and everything.

Comment: I really can't. It's gathered dynamically via an ajax call to a database full of information I really cannot share on here. I'm not really sure how that would help though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use linkedTo option http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.linkedTo

Comment: from looking at the use case examples for linkedTo in the documentation I would probably go ahead and say no, linkedTo isn't the answer I'm looking for :(

Comment: closest thing to an answer really, i've decided to use a single chart instead of two separate ones and then using linkedTo

Answer (score 1):

xAxis is an object

Maybe can you just declare this object outside highcharts methode. 
Inside both highcharts methode use the declared object.

Comment: I don't think this is it. If I were to do that, I would just be saying

`var xAxis = { type: "datetime"
}`

which would be essentially be the same as what I have now.

Comment: Can you create a jsfindle with an example of your work ? its easier to submit an answer